# Obtaining the node type being added with php

Tags: nodes

Other than pulling the information from the url itself, is there a way to retrieve/obtain the node type that has been selected in the add content area. ie: www.mydomain.com/node/add/article... using PHP? I have been able to do this when updating/editing a node using menu_get_object() in a template file but not when adding a node.

Answer (score 1):

If you are changing the form used to create a node, then you could use the following code.

```
function mymodule_form_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $node = $form_state['node'];
  if (!isset($node->nid) || isset($node->is_new)) {
    // The node is being created.
    // Use $node->type to get the content type of the node.
  }
}
```

The reason is that [node_add()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.pages.inc/function/node_add/7), the page callback for the node creation form, contains the following code.

```
  $types = node_type_get_types();
  $node = (object) array(
    'uid' => $user->uid,
    'name' => (isset($user->name) ? $user->name : ''),
    'type' => $type,
    'language' => LANGUAGE_NONE,
  );
  drupal_set_title(t('Create @name', array('@name' => $types[$type]->name)), PASS_THROUGH);
  $output = drupal_get_form($type . '_node_form', $node);
```

This means that the form used when creating a node is the node edit form.

As alternative, if you need to change the node creating form when the content type is, for example, article, you can use the following code.

```
function mymodule_form_article_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $node = $form_state['node'];
  if (!isset($node->nid) || isset($node->is_new)) {
    // The node is being created.
  }
}
```

As in this case the form is altered only when article is the content type of the node, you don't actually need to check the content type.

If you need that information in other cases, then you can only get it from the URL.

Comment: thanks kiamlaluno. I will have a look at node_add(). Where do I put the custom form function?

Comment: The code I am showing in my answer is not a custom form function, but an implementation of [hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter/7), which can be placed in a theme, or a module. Its purpose is modifying the form. If you are not doing that, you should not implement that hook.

Comment: Thanks. I'll have a look at hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter() link too.